# How to install and set up OpenCV 2.6.1 for Qt Creator in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu

For three whole days I have traversed the internet for guides on how to install and set up OpenCV in Ubuntu, with the goal of using it in my Qt Creator projects. Most guides have taken me a long way, but not once did I end up with a working solution.

Is there a single, up-to-date tutorial that covers this procedure?

Comment: This is **not** how it works in SO. If you want to share the solution you've found to others, you should do it in a Q&A form. Ask the question and answer it yourself (and accept the answer) to keep it for future references.

Comment: Hi! I selected the Q&A option when I wrote the post, so I am surprised to see it formatted like this. Is the Q&A box in the post editor the kind of Q&A you talk of?

Comment: Alright, so I tried to make it Q&A, but I cannot accept my own solution until two days have passed. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

To answer the question myself, i found this guide:

> https://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/wiki/Documentation

This guide is straight forward, and well explained. I cleaned my installation of OpenCV before trying it, with good results - it worked right away!

> Configuration: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Qt Creator 2.72 Based on Qt v5.1.0
>   64bit, OpenCV v2.6.1